# Error in javascript code if I wrote runat="server"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Code in html:

```
        <input type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly" />

        <div class="file_input_div">
          <input type="button" value="Search files" class="file_input_button" />
          <input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" onchange="javascript: document.getElementsByName('fileName')[0].value = this.value" />
        </div>
```

It's work correctly. But if i will write like this:

```
<input runat="server" type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly" />

    <div class="file_input_div">
      <input type="button" value="Search files" class="file_input_button" />
      <input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" onchange="javascript: document.getElementsByName('fileName')[0].value = this.value" />
    </div>
```

it doesnt't work woth error:
document.getElementsByName(...).0' is null or not an object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add the `runat="server"` then the `id` and the `name` is rendered different and may change by asp.net

To get the rendered name you use the `UniqueID` and get it as `<%=fileName.UniqueID%>`, so your code **as it is** must be done:

```
<input runat="server" type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly" />

    <div class="file_input_div">
      <input type="button" value="Search files" class="file_input_button" />
      <input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" 
         onchange="javascript: document.getElementsByName('<%=fileName.UniqueID%>')[0].value = this.value" />
    </div>
```

I verify it and thats the way, the name and ids change when this is added inside a master page. If they are alone on a page with out master page, then they stay as it is, but if you added them on a master page, they change and you need to get them by the rendered id.

Note that the `clientidmode="Static"` on the input control is not working for the `name` but only for the `id` so if you add it and try to keep the id the same, then you must get your element by id and not by name.

Comment: Hi @Aristos, after searching a lot for dynamic name attribute I got your answer (others were mentioning `ClientIDMode`, `ClientID`) but it has nothing to do with `name`, I tried your solution but it's saying `The name 'fileName' does not exist in the current context` in both master as well as normal page, Please help.

Comment: @RahulSingh the `fileName` is the `id` of the input control above !

Comment: Awesome! Thnx a ton :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the id of the control but the problem if you have master page, and you are using 
a template or grid then the id will be changed. So you can set the client id mode to static so that in this case it will not be changed

Example

< input runat="server" type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly" />

Or you can get the client id of the control.

Example :

document.getElementById(<%= fileName.ClientID %>);

Hope this is helpful..

Comment: The name is change even if you use static mode on client id.